# How to understand the order of convergence $\|x_{k+1} - x\| \le C \|x_k - x\|^p$ (Convergence of a power function form)?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

> By definition, a sequence $x_k \in \mathbb{R}, k \in \mathbb{N}$
>   converges with order $p \in [1,\infty)$ to $x := \lim_{k\to\infty}
>  x_k$ if  \begin{align} \exists C \in [0,\infty): \forall k \in
>  \mathbb{N}: \|x_{k+1} - x\| \le C \|x_k - x\|^p \end{align}

Assume $x_k$ is a sequence of approximations to $x$, then $\|x_k - x\|$ denotes the error of approximation at $k$-th iteration, and goes to zero as $k \to \infty$. I can understand the inequality $\|x_{k+1} - x\| \le C \|x_k - x\|$ that implies the error must go smaller and smaller along the iterations. But I don't understand the motivation to put a power of $p$ on the previous step. Any practical meaning of taking $p$-th power of error $\|x_k - x\|^p$?

Comment: Roughly speaking, order of convergence determines how many valid digits you get per iteration. If $p=1$ (linear convergence), you get approximately a constant amount per iteration, if $p=2$, the number of valid digits is approximately doubled per iteration. In general, you get about $p$ times more valid digits per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sequence of positive numbers $x_n$ such that $x_{n+1} = x_n^p$ with $p > 1$ and $x_0 < 1$. That's a special case, where $C = 1$.

Now take the logarithm. You should then be able to find an explicit formula for $x_n$. As $p$ varies, how does the rate change at which $x_n$ converges to 0? For example, how many steps are needed to guarantee $x_n < \varepsilon$ for a given $\varepsilon$?

By the way, the estimate $\|x_{k+1} - x\| \le C \|x_k - x\|$ does **not** imply that the error goes to zero. This happens only if $C < 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand why we put $p$-th power on the $x_n$. By taking logarithm we have $\log(x_{n+1}) = p \log(x_n)$. If $p=2$, say quadratic convergence, it implies $x_{n+1} > x_n$, but $x_{n+1}$ should be smaller if the sequence converges.